# Relatório de ranking de vendas

Tags: sql-server

Eu uso esse comando SQL para fazer um ranking de vendas

SQL:

```
SELECT VENDEDOR,SUM(TOTAL) AS GERAL FROM VENDAS
GROUP BY VENDEDOR
ORDER BY SUM(TOTAL) DESC;
```

Resultado:

```
VENDEDOR | VALOR
FULANO1  | 1000
FULANO2  | 800
FULANO3  | 700
FULANO4  | 100
```

Gostaria de fazer esse mesmo resultado entre datas, só que o resultado no que fiz, ele faz dia a dia. Mais não quero dia a dia e sim o total.

O SQL que fiz ficou assim:

SQL:

```
SELECT DATAVENDA,VENDEDOR,SUM(TOTAL) AS GERAL FROM VENDAS
GROUP BY DATAVENDA,VENDEDOR
ORDER BY DATAVENDA,SUM(TOTAL) DESC;
```

Resultado:

```
 DATAVENDA | VENDEDOR | TOTAL
01/04/2015 |FULANO1   | 700
01/04/2015 |FULANO2   | 600
02/04/2015 |FULANO1   | 300
02/04/2015 |FULANO2   | 200
```

Uso somente uma tabela com o nome de VENDAS e os campos são:

```
DATAVENDA(TIPO DATA),VENDEDOR(TIPO STRING),VALOR(TIPO MOEDA).
```

Tem um jeito ou maneira de fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: Você quer o resultado total entre duas datas? Se for isso, é preciso alterar um pouco seu SQL. Exemplo: `SELECT VENDEDOR, SUM(TOTAL) AS GERAL FROM VENDAS WHERE DATAVENDA BETWEEN '2014-12-04' AND '2014-12-08' GROUP BY VENDEDOR ORDER BY SUM(TOTAL) DESC;`

Comment: Amigo,desculpe mais sou novo aqui, mais o que eu uso é o sqlserver.

Comment: Rafael já deu um erro, pois na select estar faltando datavenda. select datavenda,vendedor, sum(total) as geral from vendas where datavenda between '2014-12-04' and '2014-12-08' group by vendedor order by sum(total) desc

Comment: Tem um exemplo de qual o resultado final que você gostaria exatamente? Algo como? `DataVenda: Dia inicial - Dia Final | Total: 500 | Vendedor: XYZ` ?

Comment: sera que nao pode ser uma select onde exista outra select dentro. Tipo, faz a pesquisa por entre datas e depois faz a soma total de cada vendedor???

Comment: Sem saber qual o resultado final que você quer, não temos como ajudar. Conforme você havia pedido um resultado mostrando somente o total e não data por data, eu havia colocado acima... mas você disse que precisa da data, então... qual o resultado final esperado por você?

Comment: O resultado é a soma total de vendas de cada vendas cada vendedor por periodo. Data inicial e data final.

Comment: Não faço ideia se vai funcionar ou não, mas faça um teste com esse SQL: `SELECT VENDEDOR, CONCAT(MAX(DATAVENDA),' ', MIN(DATAVENDA)) AS DATAS, SUM(TOTAL) AS GERAL FROM VENDAS WHERE DATAVENDA BETWEEN '2014-12-04' AND '2014-12-08' GROUP BY VENDEDOR ORDER BY SUM(TOTAL) DESC;`

Comment: Vou testar, assim que der certo aqui ti aviso ainda hoje. Até mais.

Comment: Rafael a sua primeira solução funcionou perfeitamente. A segunda não conseguir executar, mais estou desde já agradecido. Obg e até a próxima colega.

Comment: Não seria só tirar a data do agrupamento !?

Comment: Como Ficaria sem o agrupamento Motta??

Answer (score 1):

Acho que pode ajudar em futuras dúvidas com uma situação parecida:

> Supondo a seguinte fonte de dados

```
datavenda   vendedor    valor
2015-04-01  FULANO1 700,00
2015-04-02  FULANO1 300,00
2015-04-01  FULANO2 600,00
2015-04-02  FULANO2 200,00
2015-04-01  FULANO3 400,00
2015-04-02  FULANO3 300,00
2015-04-01  FULANO4 30,00
2015-04-02  FULANO4 70,00
2015-04-01  FULANO1 1500,00
2015-04-01  FULANO1 350,00
2015-04-02  FULANO1 750,00
2015-04-02  FULANO1 300,00
2015-04-01  FULANO2 1800,00
2015-04-01  FULANO3 600,00
2015-04-01  FULANO4 800,00
2015-04-03  FULANO1 1500,00
2015-04-03  FULANO2 3000,00
2015-04-04  FULANO4 6000,00
```

A query abaixo traz o total de cada vendedor entre uma data incial e uma data final.

```
declare @dt_inicio date
declare @dt_fim date
set @dt_inicio = '2015-04-01'
set @dt_fim = '2015-04-04'

  SELECT distinct @dt_inicio as [inicio],
         @dt_fim as [fim],
         A.vendedor, soma.v as [TOTAL] 

  from VENDAS AS A

  cross apply (

                select sum(valor) v from VENDAS 
                where datavenda between @dt_inicio and @dt_fim 
                and vendedor = A.vendedor 

               ) soma

  where datavenda between @dt_inicio and @dt_fim

  order by soma.v DESC
```

> Resultado:

```
2015-04-01  2015-04-04  FULANO4 6900,00
2015-04-01  2015-04-04  FULANO2 5600,00
2015-04-01  2015-04-04  FULANO1 5400,00
2015-04-01  2015-04-04  FULANO3 1300,00
```

Para incrementar, podemos adicionar o % correspondente a cada vendedor dentro do período pesquisado.

```
SELECT distinct @dt_inicio as [inicio],
         @dt_fim as [fim],
         A.vendedor, soma.v as [TOTAL],
         format((soma.v / soma2.v), 'p') as [% sobre TOTAL NO PERÍODO]

  from VENDAS AS A

  cross apply (

                select sum(valor) v from VENDAS 
                where datavenda between @dt_inicio and @dt_fim 
                and vendedor = A.vendedor 

               ) soma

   cross apply (

                select sum(valor) v from VENDAS 
                where datavenda between @dt_inicio and @dt_fim                 

               ) soma2

  where datavenda between @dt_inicio and @dt_fim

  order by soma.v DESC
```

> Resultado:

```
2015-04-01  2015-04-04  FULANO4 6900,00 35,93%
2015-04-01  2015-04-04  FULANO2 5600,00 29,16%
2015-04-01  2015-04-04  FULANO1 5400,00 28,12%
2015-04-01  2015-04-04  FULANO3 1300,00 6,77%
```

Eu tenho por hábito sempre guardar datas no formato americano. Para formatar pro Brasil é só usar:

```
...
 format(@dt_inicio, 'dd/MM/yyyy')as [inicio],
 format(@dt_fim, 'dd/MM/yyyy')as [fim], ...
```

Se preferir, não é preciso deixar as datas `@dt_inicio as [inicio], @dt_fim as [fim]` no select. Pode-se retirar para retornar nas linhas apenas o nome e o total de cada vendedor.